# What is tunneling in network

Tags: networking, tunnel

In my understanding, if A wants to communicate with B, they could just choose some protocol and start communicating.

For example, they pick HTTP for short links, then B just waits for A's requests and then responds to A, that's it.

Or they could choose TCP to keep the connection for a while for some real-time/two-way communications and once it's done they just close it, and that's it. End of the story.

But why we need an extra term like tunnel and why we call it that?

If two points establish a connection then it's called a connection over some protocol, why there is something like HTTP tunnel or XXX tunnel?

Also I read about the `OSI` which contains 7 layers.

**So may I say this**:

When we are browsing the websites, most requests and responses are based on `HTTP`, right?

But `HTTP` is the top layer which requires the `network layer/IP` as well as `transport layer/TCP`, and my `HTTP packages` would be encapsulated and sent to `IP layer` which would then encapsulate them into `IP packages` and the same to `TCP packages` and all the way down to the `physical layer`.

May I say that this process is like tunneling? Since the origin packages (`HTTP packages`) are being encapsulated several times in order to fit the lower layers.

I've read some wiki and definitions but that's a little bit complex for all the details, but here I just want to know the impression or the original intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When we are browsing the websites, most requests and responses are based on HTTP, right?

Yes.

> But HTTP is the top layer which requires the network layer/IP as well as transport layer/TCP, and my HTTP packages would be encapsulated and sent to IP layer which would then encapsulate them into IP packages and the same to TCP packages and all the way down to the physical layer.

Generally, yes.

Often there is SSL/TLS layered between HTTP and TCP; I guess TLS would fit the "session" layer somewhat.

> May I say that this process is like tunneling? Since the origin packages (HTTP packages) are being encapsulated several times in order to fit the lower layers.

Maybe, but not quite. In most cases the term 'tunnelling' is used when encapsulating *lower-layer* protocols inside same- or higher-layer ones (i.e. in a way that completely doesn't fit the models). The act of encapsulation is still the same in either case, but the term indicates the regular hierarchy isn't being followed.

For example, tunneling HTTP over(/inside) SSH; tunneling IPv6 over IPv4; tunneling L3 IP or even L2 Ethernet over a UDP/IP-based VPN; even tunneling IP over HTTP – the only limits are your imagination … and MTU.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:  A `tunnel` is a way to encapsulate one network protocol within another.  VPN is a common example of a tunnel: the VPN client connects to the server over the VPN protocol, then other network protocols send their packets to the VPN, which transmits those packets *using the VPN protocol* to the other side of the VPN, which then re-transmits the packets on their original protocol.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, can I say this: when we are browsing the websites, most requests and responses are based on `HTTP`, right? But `HTTP` is the top layer which requires the `network layer/IP` as well as `transport layer/TCP`, and my `HTTP request packages` would be encapsulated to `IP` which would then encapsulate its `IP packages` to `TCP packages` and all the way down to the `physical layer`, may I say this process is `tunneling`?